# Build docker image works local but doesn't work on docker hub - cmake

Tags: c++, docker, opencv, cmake

I have created a simple Dockerfile and posted this on github.
https://github.com/Josvds/dotnetopencv

When running this on my local machine (after `docker system prune`) works fine

```
[ 76%] Building CXX object modules/cvv/CMakeFiles/opencv_cvv.dir/src/qtutil/matchview/keypointvaluechooser.cpp.o
[ 76%] Building CXX object modules/cvv/CMakeFiles/opencv_cvv.dir/src/qtutil/matchview/matchintervallselection.cpp.o
[ 76%] Building CXX object modules/cvv/CMakeFiles/opencv_cvv.dir/src/qtutil/matchview/matchmanagement.cpp.o
[ 76%] Building CXX object modules/cvv/CMakeFiles/opencv_cvv.dir/src/qtutil/matchview/matchportionselector.cpp.o
[ 76%] Building CXX object modules/aruco/CMakeFiles/opencv_aruco.dir/src/aruco.cpp.o
[ 77%] Linking CXX shared library ../../lib/libopencv_xobjdetect.so
[ 77%] Building CXX object modules/cvv/CMakeFiles/opencv_cvv.dir/src/qtutil/matchview/matchscene.cpp.o
[ 77%] Built target opencv_xobjdetect
[ 77%] Processing OpenCL kernels (bioinspired)
Scanning dependencies of target opencv_bioinspired
[ 78%] Building CXX object modules/bioinspired/CMakeFiles/opencv_bioinspired.dir/src/basicretinafilter.cpp.o
[ 78%] Building CXX object modules/rgbd/CMakeFiles/opencv_rgbd.dir/src/dynafu_tsdf.cpp.o
[ 78%] Building CXX object modules/cvv/CMakeFiles/opencv_cvv.dir/src/qtutil/matchview/matchselectionselector.cpp.o
[ 78%] Building CXX object modules/cvv/CMakeFiles/opencv_cvv.dir/src/qtutil/matchview/matchsettingsselector.cpp.o
```

But when this is build bij docker-hub I get the follow error. Tried it already twice by triggering a build again, but doesn't help.

```
[ 77%] Generating qrc_window_QT.cpp
[91mRCC: Error in '/opencv/opencv/modules/highgui/src/window_QT.qrc': Cannot find file 'files_Qt/Milky/48/28.png'
[0m
[91mmake[2]: *** [modules/highgui/CMakeFiles/opencv_highgui.dir/build.make:78: modules/highgui/qrc_window_QT.cpp] Error 1
[0m
[91mmake[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/Makefile2:4375: modules/highgui/CMakeFiles/opencv_highgui.dir/all] Error 2
[0m
[91mmake: *** [Makefile:163: all] Error 2
[0m
Removing intermediate container 7f068cac93e1
The command '/bin/sh -c make -j$(nproc)' returned a non-zero code: 2
```

I have checked opencv on git https://github.com/opencv/opencv/tree/4.3.0/modules/highgui/src/files_Qt/Milky/48 where that file is available.

**Update 15-04-2020**
I have now executed the same file not on my windows system but on my linux environment which also has docker. This is running debian 9.12 and Docker version 19.03.8. Also on this system the build is completed successfully. Yesterday I started it again on docker-hub and again same error.

Anyone what I do wrong?